# Why are my PyGame images stored local to the program not loading?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

All images are within the folder of the game. (using mac)
I get no errors, but the images just dont load. Just a plain white screen.

I have tried everything and I may give up at this point. I am begging you to please, please, please help me!

My program is super long, and I know that what I am asking is insane, but I have been trying to fix this for over 2 weeks!

I hope I have made a small mistake, and it isnt a larger issue!

Sorry about this!

```
import pygame
pygame.init()



display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hack Attack')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()



charUp = pygame.image.load('StandUp.png') #Can also be used for down
charDown = pygame.image.load('StandUp.png')
charLeft = pygame.image.load('StandLeft.png') #Can also be used for right
charRight = pygame.image.load('StandLeft.png')
UpFor1 = pygame.image.load('Upfor1.png') #Can also be used for Down Forward 2
DownFor2 = pygame.image.load('Upfor1.png')
UpFor2 = pygame.image.load('UpFor2.png')
DownFor1 = pygame.image.load('UpFor2.png')
LeftFor1 = pygame.image.load('LeftFor1.png')
RightFor2 = pygame.image.load('LeftFor1.png')
RightFor1 = pygame.image.load('LeftFor2.png')
LeftFor2 = pygame.image.load('LeftFor2.png')

UpCount = 0
LeftCount = 0
RightCount = 0
DownCount = 0  





character = pygame.image.load('StandUp.png')








x = (display_width * 0.5)
y = (display_height * 0.5)

def gameLoop():
    global character
    global UpCount
    global DownCount
    global LeftCount
    global RightCount
    global y
    global x
    global x_change
    global y_change


    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0





    crashed = False

    while not crashed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                crashed = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:


                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    LeftCount += 1
                    x_change = -5
                    character = charLeft

                    if LeftCount % 2 == 0:
                        x = LeftCount/4
                        try:

                            x = int(x)
                        except ValueError:
                            character = LeftFor1
                        else:
                            character = LeftFor2
                    else:
                        character = charLeft





                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    y_change = -5
                    character = charRight

                    DownCount += 1
                    character = charDown

                    if DownCount % 2 == 0:
                         x = DownCount/4
                         try:
                            x = int(x)

                         except ValueError:
                            character = DownFor1
                         else:
                            character = DownFor2
                         pass


                    else:
                        character = charDown

                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    y_change = 5
                    character = charRight
                    UpCount += 1
                    character = charUp
                    x = UpCount
                    if DownCount % 2 == 0:
                        x = UpCount/4
                        try:
                            x = int(x)
                        except ValueError:
                            character = UpFor1
                        else:
                            character = UpFor2
                    else:
                        character = charUp

                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    x_change = 5
                    character = charRight

                    RightCount += 1
                    character = charRight
                    x = RightCount/4
                    if DownCount % 2 == 0:
                        x = RightCount/4
                        try:
                            x = int(x)
                        except ValueError:
                            character = UpFor1
                        else:
                            character = UpFor2
                    else:
                        character = charUp






            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    x_change = 0
                    y_change = 0


        x = x + x_change
        y = y + y_change

        white = [255, 255, 255]


        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.blit(character,(x,y))
        print('x ' + str(x) + ' y ' + str(y))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(20)

gameLoop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you attach one of the images to the question?  Maybe there's something weird in the .PNG?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try checking if your character image is being displayed outside the bounds of your game window, like setting the x and y variables to 400 and 300, this way you know your image is going to be put in the center of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import it...
from pygame.locals import *

I am not sure that it would work or not but try it once...

Comment: if still it's not working try to place all images in another folder and get them by importing os and getting them by pygame.image.load(os.path.join('folder name','image_name')).convert()